# Is there a clear "Cycle" in UI/Grpahic styling?

Tags: style, graphic-styles

As you will be aware design styles go in waves, IE flat, clear/opaque, curved,  fades, tiles, minimalist, retro, halftone etc etc - often styles come back into fashion, and often it is a design industry-wide change.
UI and Graphic (for print/web) are now inseparable as they are often involved in a single product/service.

Is there as yet any clear cycle that these style types are appearing in? do they tend to follow the cycle of certain design houses or companies?

Comment: Great question. I think the cyclical nature of design follows a natural pattern, although it is steered and influenced by new techniques and technology. The pattern it follow is the same as many cycles in nature: something new and novel provides an advantage until it is so copied that it becomes ubiquitous. When someone removes the new design the effect is to make it look cleaner, simpler and more traditional, so now not having it provides an advantage.